# Insert comment to database with the right ID to match and ad (php , mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, comments

Im trying to make so that you can comment on an ad, on a buy/sell site.

On the main page im showing all the ads (all ad’s have an id named AdID) and under every ad i have a comment section.

My problem is that I cant seem to pass my AdID from the right ad to the if statement where I make my INSERT statement.

I could solve it by having the comment section on a different page and pass the AdID with $_GET but I really want people to be able to comment under the ad on the main page.

Help would be appreciated and if you need the rest of the code please say so.

```
    $res2 = $mysqli->query($query) or die("Could not query database" . $mysqli->errno . " : " . $mysqli->error); //Performs query 

     while($row2 = $res2->fetch_object()) {

    $Comment = utf8_decode(htmlspecialchars($row2->Comment));
    $AdID = utf8_decode(htmlspecialchars($row2->AdID));
    $UserID = utf8_decode(htmlspecialchars($row2->UserID));
    $Fname1 = utf8_decode(htmlspecialchars($row2->Fname));
    $Lname1 = utf8_decode(htmlspecialchars($row2->Lname));   

    $c .= <<<END

 <div class="CommentBox">
 {$Fname1} {$Lname1}

 {$Comment}
 </div>
 END;

 }

    if(!empty($_POST)) {


    $msg = utf8_encode($mysqli->real_escape_string($msg));  
    $UserID = isset($_SESSION["UserID"]) ? $_SESSION["UserID"] : "NULL";

    $query = <<<END
    INSERT INTO comment (Comment, UserID, AdID) 
    VALUES('{$msg}', '{$UserID}' , '{$AdID}' ); 
END;

    $res = $mysqli->query($query) or die("Could not query database" . $mysqli-    >errno . " : " . $mysqli->error); //Performs query 

}

$c .= <<<END

        <form action="comTest.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="stor" name="msg" value="{$msg}"   placeholder="Comment"/>
        </form>

END;


}
```

Comment: You did not handled form correctly. See my answer further details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't get `msg` value posted from form. You need to get it first;

```
$msg = $_POST["msg"];
```

And also, put a hidden element to form so, you can get ad ID like;

```
<form action="comTest.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="stor" name="msg" value="{$msg}"   placeholder="Comment"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="adId" name="adId" value="$AdID"/>
</form>
```